# What is the most efficient way to modify a Keras Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Is there a way to add nodes to a layer in an existing Keras model? if so, what is the most efficient way to do so?

Also, is it possible to do the same but with layers? i.e. add a new layer to an existing Keras model (for example, right after the input layer).

One way I know of is to use Keras functional API by iterating and cloning each layer of the model in order to create a "copy" of the original model with the desired changes, but is it the most efficient way to accomplish this task?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Taking a model and `.add()`ing things?

Comment: @AKX Let's say I want to add a layer right after the input layer, the `.add` the function would add the layer to the end of the network, which is not what I want.

Comment: You can do something like `output_i = model.layers[i].output` and then pass `output_i` as input to another layer/model.

Comment: @jdehesa can you provide an example, please? I think this may be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the output of a layer in a model and build another model starting from it:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# One simple model
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(3,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

# Make a second model starting from layer in previous model
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu')(model.layers[1].output)
outputs2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax')(x2)
model2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=outputs2)
```

Note that in this case `model` and `model2` share the same input layer and first dense layer objects (`model.layers[0] is model2.layers[0]` and `model.layers[1] is model2.layers[1]`).